# I want to open a text file and edit a specific line in java

Tags: java

This is code i Have written instead of editing a particular line new name gets appened at the last...
please help me out....

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
        new FileWriter("d:\\book.txt", true)));

BufferedReader br = null;
FileReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new FileReader("d:\\book.txt");
    br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line;
    System.out.println((";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;" + request
            .getParameter("hname")));
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("book"));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if (request.getParameter("hname").equals(line)) {
            line = line.replace(request.getParameter("hname"),
                    request.getParameter("book"));

            writer.println(line);

            writer.close();
        }
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    reader.close();

}
```

Comment: can you tell me what `request` is?

Comment: `FileWriter("d:\\book.txt", true)` will append !!!!

Answer (score 7):

Unless you aren't changing the (byte) length of the line, you need to rewrite the whole file, adding the changed line where appropriate. This is actually just a simple change from your current code. First, initialize your `FileWriter` without the `append` (since you **don't** want to just append to the end of the file, which is what you're doing now).

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("d:\\book.txt")));
```

Then, either read the whole file into memory (if the file is small enough) or else write a temp file as you go and then copy it over when you're done. The second way is more robust, and requires less code changing; just modify your while loop to write every line, modified or not.

```
// Open a temporary file to write to.
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("d:\\book.temp")));

// ... then inside your loop ...

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (request.getParameter("hname").equals(line)) {
        line = line.replace(request.getParameter("hname"),
                request.getParameter("book"));
    }
    // Always write the line, whether you changed it or not.
    writer.println(line);
}

// ... and finally ...

File realName = new File("d:\\book.txt");
realName.delete(); // remove the old file
new File("d:\\book.temp").renameTo(realName); // Rename temp file
```

Don't forget to close all your file handles when you're done!

Comment: Java 7 update - you can let Java handle closing resources with the try-with-resources block. the Oracle tutorial for this is found at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: @Henry, is there a faster way to do this if you aren't changing the byte length of the file, eg: the contents that you are changing the line to are the same byte length?

Comment: @OfekGila If you know you're not changing the byte length, you can use a `RandomAccessFile` to seek in and simply overwrite any part of the file that you want. In my experience this tends to cause trouble down the road, though.