# How can I write to a specific line number in a txt file in Java

Tags: java, file, text, file-io, randomaccessfile

I'm currently writing my project for school in which requires me to read and write to txt files. I can read them correctly but I can only write to them at the end from an appended FileWriter. I would like to be able to overwrite things in my txt files on line numbers by first deleting the data on the line and then writing in the new data. I attempted to use this method...

```
public void overWriteFile(String dataType, String newData) throws IOException
{
    ReadFile file = new ReadFile(path);
    RandomAccessFile ra = new RandomAccessFile(path, "rw");
    int line = file.lineNumber(path, dataType);
    ra.seek(line);
    ra.writeUTF(dataType.toUpperCase() + ":" + newData);
}
```

but I believe that the seek method moves along in bytes rather than line numbers. Can anyone help. Thanks in advance :)

P.S. the file.lineNumber method returns the exact line that the old data was on so I already have the line number that needs to be written to.

EDIT: Soloution found! Thanks guys :) I'll post the soloution below if anyone is interested

```
public void overWriteFile(String dataType, String newData, Team team, int dataOrder) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        ReadFile fileRead = new ReadFile(path);
        String data = "";
        if(path == "res/metadata.txt")
        {
            data = fileRead.getMetaData(dataType);
        }
        else if(path == "res/squads.txt")
        {
            data = fileRead.getSquadData(dataType, dataOrder);
        }
        else if(path == "res/users.txt")
        {
            data = fileRead.getUsernameData(dataType, dataOrder);
        }
        else if(path == ("res/playerdata/" + team.teamname + ".txt"))
        {
            //data = fileRead.getPlayerData(dataType, team.teamname, dataOrder);
        }
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        String line;
        String input = "";
        while((line = file.readLine()) != null)
        {
            input += line + '\n';
        }
        input = input.replace(dataType.toUpperCase() + ":" + data, dataType.toUpperCase() + ":" + newData);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
        out.write(input.getBytes());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error overwriting file: " + path);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't know the length of each line, you can't access a given line randomly. Just copy all the lines untile the one you're looking for, then write its replacement, then write the rest of the lines.

Comment: If you found the solution- rather than posting it in the question, post it as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution would be to use the `Files.readAllLines` and `Files.write` methods to read all lines, change the one you want to change, and overwrite the whole file:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
lines.set(line, dataType.toUpperCase() + ":" + newData);
Files.write(file.toPath(), lines); // You can add a charset and other options too
```

Of course, that's not a good idea if it's a very big file. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20040289/3801695) for some ideas on how to copy the file line by line in that case.

Regardless of how you do it, though, if you are changing the byte length of the line, you will need to rewrite the whole file (AFAIK). RandomAcessFile allows you to move around the file and overwrite data, but not to insert new bytes or removes existing ones, so the length of the file (in bytes) will stay the same.

Comment: Well, you certainly need not copy the data that comes before the line in question. The data after it needs to be shifted by the difference introduced by the edit. If the file is huge and the edited line is near the end, it might pay off. It might be crucial if the file is so large that an additional working copy will not fit the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a question just like this with a great answer:
[I want to open a text file and edit a specific line in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218971/i-want-open-a-text-file-and-edit-a-specific-line-in-java)

Basically, you can't just edit that line, unless it'll be the exact same length.

Instead, you'll want to copy over every line, and then when you reach the line number of the line you want to change, instead of copying over the old line, just put in your new line.

The link I gave you has a great example on how to do this.

I hope this helps...if not, let me know, and I'll elaborate further on the post. Good luck :)